# windows phone 8.1 company profile

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, certificate, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

We are developing the Windows Phone 8.1 app.
The Hockeyapp was chosen for app distribution. To be able to distribute a Windows Phone 8.1 app, it requires to upload the company profile file (.aetx). Which then should be downloaded on Windows Phone and only after that the .xib file signed with the company certificate can be installed.

The problem is that the phone reports the error when trying to install the .aetx file:

> Can't add workplace account
>
> > We weren't able to set up the workplace account.
> >     Contact your company's support person for help.

The specifics is that the Enterprise Mobile Code Signing Certificate was requested from Symantec from the Mac computer, and the certificates were exported to .p12 format but not .pfx as in case of Windows OS. But the AETGenerator.exe didn't show any error and successfully created the .aet, .aetx and .xml files.

I followed the [Company app distribution for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), and the steps I have done:

- Registered the Company account on Windows Phone Dev Center
- On Mac computer applied for Symantec Enterprise Mobile Code Signing
  Certificate
- On Mac picked up Enterprise Certificate from Symantec
- On Mac exported the Enterprise Certificate to .p12 file
- On Windows installed the Symantec_Enterprise_Mobile_Root_for_Microsoft.cer
- On Windows installed the Symantec_Enterprise_Mobile_CA_for_Microsoft_Cert.cer
- On Windows development computer generated the .aetx file using the AETGenerator.exe of the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK tools

Now either installing the .aetx file from email or through Hockeyapp the phone shows the same error and doesn't install the certificate.

I tried installing the .p12 from Mac to Windows, then exporting the .pfx file on Windows with included private certificate, and then generating the .aetx file from this .pfx, the result is the same; phone shows the same error.

If I install all certificates on Windows (downloading Symantec certificates and installing private and public Enterprise certificates from .p12 file), and then trying to pick up the Enterprise Certificate from Symantec on Windows, the browser shows:

> Your certificate cannot be installed. Either it has already been installed, or you have removed your private key.

It seems this error is shown when trying to install the public key of certificate not on the same computer from where it was requested.

Can applying for Symantec Enterprise Mobile Code Signing Certificate from Mac and then exporting the certificate be the reason of this problem?

If the Enterprise Mobile Code Signing Certificate was once acquired for the company, is there a way to apply for another certificate for same company from another computer? When  enrolling for a certificate, the private key is being created [in the browser on the back end](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/93301237-ba89-4f2b-9aa2-78f1de935ca0/not-able-to-install-enetrprise-mobile-code-sign-certificate), and I am thinking if it is possible to pass the same procedure from Windows but not paying for extra certificate.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.
When we try to generate AET token, it fails with following error? What is cause for this failure?

Unknown Error while generating AET

StartIndex cannot be larger than length of string

Parameter name: StartIndex

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/04/21/frequently-asked-questions-about-windows-phone-company-hub-apps.aspx